# What does the torn sheet of paper icon in outliner mean?

Tags: outliner

What does torn sheet of paper mean? And how repair it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means file missing or broken link. In this case it might mean that the linked file that contains the object (or collection) cannot be found in the disk. Did you move, rename or delete any files?.

To find the error, switch the outliner display the blender file mode and look for missing libraries.

[image]

Or display API data, navigate to the missing collection and find what is it that is linked to. You can re-link it to the original file by manually typing the correct path.

[image]

When you get an error like this,you can also check the terminal output. It should report something like:

[image]

Comment: But this is not linked object. It's appended object.

Comment: If you think this is not the case please upload your file and make it available as part of the question so that users can help you determine the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for a such detailed answer.) I have actually moved the linked file.

But now I don't understand why link or append is needed?
So if I want to save my collection/object in the new file forever, I just need to open the library(.blend file) and copy/paste the collection/object I need. And then I don't have to worry about moving or deleting the the linked file accidentally.

Comment: I just know that broken link is that icon. Maybe you didn't append and just linked.